# Is there a way to put an split an ISO file onto 2 USB drives too small for it?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, iso-image

So I have 2 4GB USB drives and I want to split an ISO file between the two of them. (As in like a "Insert Disk 2" situation) Are there anyways I can go about doing this? All of the questions I've seen so far are "How to split the install.wim so it fits on FAT32". But the catch is that their USB drives can fit the ISO itself. Also, how would I get the Windows Installation to recognise when to put the second drive in?

Comment: Is it specifically a Windows ISO with install.wim in it, or is it some other type of ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. As simple as that.
The ISO format doesn't have any provisions for that.

The software-setup itself on the disk would need to know which item is on which disk and ask for the next disk as appropriate.
This is possible and was done frequently in the past when media was smaller.  Software came on multiple floppies and later CD's or DVD's.
(Windows 3.1 was 6 3.5" floppies, or 9 if you needed networking. Windows 95 also still had a floppy version (25 or so if I remember correctly).)

But the point is: those installers were designed for this from the start. Retro-fitting it later to an existing software-installation is next to impossible. (It can be done in some cases, but you need a very deep understanding of the internals of that particular setup-process.)

Since USB sticks are so cheap nobody bothers and just gets bigger sticks.

Answer (score 0):

There are [official Microsoft instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds?view=windows-11) for this. They say:

> Applying split image (.swm) files is only supported when all of the .swm files are in the same folder. This means for DVD deployment, you'll need to copy the files over to the destination PC before you can use Windows Setup or DISM /Apply-Image, as shown in this topic.

Although your USB sticks aren't exactly DVDs, it's still practically the same situation.

You will need to use a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> console window to copy the files to a temporary partition (on a different disk would be easiest) and use `setup /InstallFrom:<path_to_swm>` to manually start Setup (instead of using the button).

(It is not required to use Setup; you could partition the target disk using DISKPART to create the EFI + Windows + temporary SWM partitions, then use DISM and BCDBOOT for the actual installation.)